# Load a pre-trained tensorflow model in C API

Tags: c++, c, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

How can I load a pre-trained model (like coco - for example) in Tensorflow C API?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get the folder of the pretrained model you want. You can save it as a tensorflow model with python, see:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Secondly, as long as you are okey with using a dynamic library I would suggest using cppflow:
https://github.com/serizba/cppflow

I suggest following their tutorial for how to install cppflow and the Tensorflow C-API here:
https://serizba.github.io/cppflow/installation.html

You have several examples of how to load and run a model in their documentation, but here's a short snippet:

#include 
#include "cppflow/cppflow.h"

```
int main() {

    auto input = cppflow::decode_jpeg(cppflow::read_file(std::string("../my_cat.jpg")));
    input = cppflow::cast(input, TF_UINT8, TF_FLOAT);
    input = cppflow::expand_dims(input, 0);
    cppflow::model model("../model");
    auto output = model(input);

    std::cout << "It's a tiger cat: " << cppflow::arg_max(output, 1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you need to use a static library I would suggest using Tensorflow Lite:

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite